# Setting vertex color with ob.data.vertex_colors["Col"].data[0].color stores values wrong

Tags: python, vertex-colors

when I set the color of vertex data with;

```
ob.data.vertex_colors["Col"].data[0].color = [0.7, 0.5, 0.3]
```

and then look at the values, they are different

```
ob.data.vertex_colors["Col"].data[0].color
Color((0.6980392336845398, 0.49803921580314636, 0.2980392277240753))
```

Why is this not saved properly?

Comment: Because the numbers are different.0.7 versus 0.698

Answer (score 4):

Vertex colours are stored as 8-bit sRGB values. This means that they have a maximum precision of 1/256, but the raw values are also further distorted by the sRGB colourspace translation.